# Shopify Theme Editor Broken

Tags: editor, admin, shopify

I can't give many specifics as the site I'm working on is not live, and of course cannot give access to Shopify Admin.

But I have an issue where in the Shopify Admin, the theme editor does not load the schema settings under the 'sections' tab.

I've reached out to Shopify for any incite, without any luck. I've modified the theme, but not sure what would cause the schema to break. See the image for what I'm talking about.

Looking for some feedback to what would cause this to occur / if there are common things to check for.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling on this. I believe it was a combination of a script / liquid tag that was present on all pages of the site that caused the conflict.